# Missing keyword error in SELECT INTO statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have this simple query:

```
SELECT *
INTO assimilations
FROM assimilations_bk
WHERE client_number='123';
```

As you can see I'm trying to insert some values from one table to another. The both tables are exactly the same, but I'm still getting a strange error that I can not understand.

After running the query I'm getting this:

```
ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 6
```

regarding this line:

```
INTO assimilations
```

What am I missing here? The syntax seems ok to me, but obviously I'm missing a small part of it.

Comment: `select .. into ..` is used to store a value from a select statement into a PL/SQL variable, not to insert into an new table. To insert rows into a table use the `insert` statement. This is all documented in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF01604

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Select into` is used for set data to variable. If you want to copy data to new table you have to use it that way:

```
insert into assimilations
SELECT *
FROM assimilations_bk
WHERE client_number='123';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be this:

```
INSERT INTO assimilations 
     (SELECT * FROM assimilations_bk WHERE client_number='123');
```